# Microsoft Office Document Imaging (MODI) for Office 2016

Tags: windows, office365, ms-office, modi

I have heard about scanned document OCR feature in MS Office 2007.

Are there similar programs which have similar/same feature compatible with Office 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my search and test, Office2016 has OCR function and you need to turn it on manually.

Please review link below for more details:

[I beieve the OCR is available in Windows 10 or Word 2016.](https://www.justanswer.com/microsoft-office/ay4of-beieve-ocr-available-windows-10-word-2016.html)